# Unify Fields in a View

Tags: sql, sql-server

I have a View like this :

```
dbo.MyTable.Element1,
dbo.MyTable2.Element1
FROM MyTable LEFT OUTER JOIN MyTable2
```

Element1s from MyTable and MyTable2 is binary(true or false). What I want to achieve is a new field which becomes 1 when at least one of the Element1s is one. How can I do that? Thanks.

Comment: Hint:  `CASE`/`AND`.  Also, SQL Server doesn't have a "binary" data type.  What is the actual data type?  Sample data and desired results are always helpful.

Comment: @GordonLinoff actual data type is bit,

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The typical way to do what you want is using `case`:

```
SELECT (CASE WHEN t.Element1 = 'true' OR t2.Element1 = 'true'
             THEN 'true' ELSE 'false'
        END)
FROM MyTable t LEFT OUTER JOIN
     MyTable2 t2
     ON . . .
```

This is just an example.  It is not clear how "true" and "false" are represented in your data.

Comment: Data type is bit, so, they are either one or zero

Answer (score 2):

For SQL Server, it could be something like this:

```
select case
    when t1.Element1 = 1 or t2.Element1 = 1 then 1 
    else 0 end
from dbo.MyTable.Element1 t1
left join MyTable2 dbo.MyTable.Element2 t2 on (...)
```

Answer (score 1):

Sql server supports [bitwise operators](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms176122.aspx), so you can write it like this:

```
SELECT dbo.MyTable.Element1 | dbo.MyTable2.Element1 
FROM MyTable 
LEFT JOIN MyTable2 -- ON <condition>
```

Answer (score 1):

You could use [bitwise operators](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms176122.aspx). Though this might be less clear than Gordon's answer.

Updated to show impact of nulls:

```
create table bitTest (a bit null, b bit null)
insert into bitTest values 
  (0,0), (1,0), (0,1) ,(1,1)
, (null,null), (null,0), (null,1) 
, (0,null), (1,null) 
select 
    a
  , b
  , bitwiseOr    = a|b
  , bitwiseAnd   = a&b
  , bitwiseXor   = a^b 
  , isnullNullif = isnull(nullif(a,0),isnull(b,0))
  , caseWhen     = convert(bit,case when a=1 or b=1 then 1 else 0 end)
from bitTest
```

Results in:

```
+-------+-------+-----------+------------+------------+--------------+----------+
|   a   |   b   | bitwiseOr | bitwiseAnd | bitwiseXor | isnullNullif | caseWhen |
+-------+-------+-----------+------------+------------+--------------+----------+
| False | False | False     | False      | False      | False        | False    |
| True  | False | True      | False      | True       | True         | True     |
| False | True  | True      | False      | True       | True         | True     |
| True  | True  | True      | True       | False      | True         | True     |
| NULL  | NULL  | NULL      | NULL       | NULL       | False        | False    |
| NULL  | False | NULL      | NULL       | NULL       | False        | False    |
| NULL  | True  | NULL      | NULL       | NULL       | True         | True     |
| False | NULL  | NULL      | NULL       | NULL       | False        | False    |
| True  | NULL  | NULL      | NULL       | NULL       | True         | True     |
+-------+-------+-----------+------------+------------+--------------+----------+
```

rextester link: http://rextester.com/SPMNK25857

---